# How to match data that does not contain a number at any place

Tags: sql, oracle

If my column has John1, John, Jo1hn, 1John..I must write a query which extracts only John i.e. *no numeric digits at any place*.

I already tried multiple options with regexp_like and below query came close

```
select * from table where  regexp_like(column,'[^[:digit:]]+$');
```

But it is only eliminating John1 which has 1 as the last character, not the others.

Let me know if the question is not clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this way:

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select 'John1' from dual union all
  3    select 'John'  from dual union all
  4    select 'Jo1hn'  from dual union all
  5    select '1John' from dual
  6  )
  7  select *
  8    from t1
  9  where regexp_like(col, '^[^[:digit:]]+$')
 10  ;

COL
-----
John
```

OR

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select 'John1' from dual union all
  3    select 'John'  from dual union all
  4    select 'Jo1hn'  from dual union all
  5    select '1John' from dual
  6  )
  7  select *
  8    from t1
  9  where regexp_like(col, '^[[:alpha:]]+$')
 10  ;

COL
-----
John
```

Comment: That worked like charm Nicholas! So adding ^ to indicate the starting of string resolved it..I missed it!

Comment: @user841311 Outer caret matches the start of the string and inner caret negates(first query) digit class

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `NOT`:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM (SELECT 'John1' txt FROM dual
  3          UNION ALL
  4          SELECT 'John' FROM dual
  5          UNION ALL
  6          SELECT 'Jo1hn' FROM dual
  7          UNION ALL
  8          SELECT '1John' FROM dual)
  9   WHERE NOT regexp_like(txt, '[[:digit:]]');

TXT
----
John
```